# Dangerous for wheel to sit in deflated tire over night?

Tags: tires, damage

I popped the front driver-side tire of my 4 door sedan by putting a tear in the sidewall. I am unable to replace the tire until tomorrow. Will letting the car sit with a deflated tire overnight damage the wheel in any way? Do I run the risk of increasing the damage (and therefore the cost) by waiting until tomorrow?

Answer (score 2):

None whatsoever. Vehicles have sat decades on flat tires with no ill effect to the wheels (unless they were sitting in water). Overnight won't cause you any problems. If you were asking about the tire itself, that might be a different story, but since you have to replace it anyways, really, nothing to worry about.

Comment: What about residual effects on other things? Suspension, etc...

Comment: @Runeaway3 - Nope ... it's not an issue. The vehicle would have to be sitting for YEARS before you'd find any issue with suspension. Seriously, there's no problem. The only way to damage it overnight is to drive directly on the rim.